# rasa not responding when setting the value of session_persistence: true using socket

Tags: python, socket.io, response, custom-action, rasa

My credentials.yml is this:

```
rest:

socketio:

user_message_evt: user_uttered

bot_message_evt: bot_uttered

session_persistence: true

rasa:
url: "http://localhost:5002/api"
```

As soon as i set **session_persistence: false**, it's  working, ie The rasa is sending the response from custom_action.

I am not receivin any error, just not getting the response when session_persistence is set to true